# How can I set individual column alignment while using siunitx?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm using the following code to make a table that will many many more rows. I want to make it so that the columns  that contain numbers will be right and left justified, like the Year row looks like. I would really like to do this without having to go to each cell and use the multicolumn command. Is there another way?

I was hoping there is something in the : `\begin{tabular}{l*{13}{S[table-align-text-post=false]}}`

But I can't figure out what the correct command would be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\begin{document}    

\begin{sidewaystable}[]
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{tbl1{tab1}}
    \sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}

    \begin{tabular}{l*{13}{S[table-align-text-post=false]}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{FT Differential (1964-2012)} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{ Scale (1986-2012)} \\ \midrule

    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dem} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rep} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Demo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rep} \\\midrule

    \textbf{V1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.207} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(3.44)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2.25} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{(4.69)} &  -3.99 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(5.81)} &    32.02\sym{***} & (4.82) &   19.27\sym{**} & (6.69) &   52.75\sym{***} & (8.22) \\

    \textbf{Year} &  7.27\sym{*} & (3.16) &  9.23\sym{*} & (4.52) &  3.65 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(5.11)} &  21.94\sym{***} & (3.97) &  19.37\sym{***} & (5.03) &   33.09\sym{***} & (7.37) \\


\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Source: }\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} $p<0.05$, \sym{**} $p<0.01$,     \sym{***} \   ($p<0.001$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use r instead of S for the columns you don't want aligned by the decimal points.  Right now every column is S.